# Executing echo c >sysrq-trigger on remote machine in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to do some automation in which following is the requirement :-

"From machine A run command "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger" on machine B so that machine B crashes and after machine B boots up (post crash) do some other things like copying files from machine b to  machine A."

For this purpose i tried the following 2 methods  :-

1. "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root  "sh //proc/sysrq-trigger command>"
2. "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root  "sh  echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger >"

In both the cases password-less ssh is set or will provide password through expect. So password is not a problem here.The problem is the control gets stuck after executing sysrq instruction on the remote machine B. It does not come back on machine A so that i can perform any other operation on the same terminal.

```
# ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root <Machine B> "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger "
```

Warning: Permanently added 'ca-ostest212.us.oracle.com,139.185.48.212' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@'s password:

After providing password machine B crashes and reboots but prompt on machine A does not come back.Is there any method to solve this so that prompt comes back and next commands get executed on machine A.

PS :- Apology for this lengthy query. Plz help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: From machine A, remotely i want to make machine B crash and check the vmcore so generated can be analyzed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented this by first creating passwordless ssh between the 2 systems and then executing the following command from the source machine.

```
ssh -l root <remote machine> "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger" &
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to see if it works:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root <Machine B> "{ sleep 2; echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger; } & exit"
```

or

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root <Machine B> "nohup sh -c 'sleep 2; echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger' & exit"
```

The idea is to background a short `sleep` along with the crash and return immediately. You might try varying the `sleep` interval. You might also try the `-f`, `-n`, `-t` or `-T` options, but that's grabbing at straws. If you use `-f` or `-n`, don't background the local `ssh` process (only the remote stuff).